# is there a way to add borders in a Text widget without wrapping it in a container widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, text-widget, flutter-text

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AT0j.png)please I need to delete the container widget and add border-radius to the text widget, or is it possible to make the text widget and container widget respond to changes together(meaning: when the text is null the container shouldn't display)

```
   child: Container(
                     padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25.0, 0, 10.0, 0),
                     decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                     color: Colors.grey[850],
                     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                     side: BorderSide(
                     width: 2.0,
                     style: BorderStyle.solid,
                     color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                     borderRadius:
                     BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                     child: Text(
                     costOfSales,
                     style: TextStyle(
                    `enter code here` color: Colors.white,
                     fontSize: 25.0,
                                      ),
                                    )),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var costOfSales = "\$99";

    return costOfSales == null
        ? Container()
        : Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25.0, 0, 10.0, 0),
            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey[850],
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side: BorderSide(
                  width: 2.0,
                  style: BorderStyle.solid,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
              ),
            ),
            child: Text(
              costOfSales,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 25.0,
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
```